# Docker Multi-stage Builds of miniconda environments

Tags: python, docker

I would like to run multi-stages build from existing conda environments? 
Unfortunately, once copied into the new image, it replies /bin/python doesn't work: `/bin/sh python: not found` when I launch the container.

Is there any trick to do so in order to reduce the image footprint of my python scripts?

Here a sample file:

```
FROM custom_image as build

....

RUN conda env create -n my_env -f env.yml

FROM python:alpine

COPY --from=build /opt/conda/ens/my_env /opt/conda/ens/my_env 
COPY other files

CMD /opt/conda/ens/my_env/bin/pyton my_script
EXPOSE 8080
```

Answer (score 1):

Copying the entire `/opt/conda` directory and setting PATH environments work for me. In your case, try something like:

```
FROM python:alpine

COPY --from=build /opt/conda/. /opt/conda/
COPY other files

ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH

CMD python my_script
EXPOSE 8080
```